# Confusion in marker interface

Tags: java, interface

Marker interface means interface which have no methods. Then why we call the Runnable interface as a marker interface, even though it has run() method.
And one more thing how many marker interfaces are there in java ?

Comment: Who calls Runnable a marker interface?

Comment: Whoever you know that so calls it is just wrong.

Answer (score 8):

> Then why we call the Runnable
>   interface as a marker interface

We don't. You just made that up.

Answer (score 6):

Runnable is not a Marker interface. AFAIK, Serializable, Clonable, SingleThreadModel, EventListener, RandomAccess, Remote are Marker Interfaces.