# How Marker Interface is handled by JVM

Tags: java, jvm

Marker interface doesn't has any thing. It contains only interface declarations, then how it is handled by the JVM for the classes which implements this marker interface?

Can we create any new marker interfaces ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your question should really be how does the **compiler** handle marker interfaces, and the answer is: *No differently from any other interface*.  For example, suppose I declare a new marker interface `Foo`:

```
public interface Foo {
}
```

... and then declare a class `Bar` that implements `Foo`:

```
public class Bar implements Foo {
  private final int i;

  public Bar(int i) { this.i = i; }
}
```

I am now able to refer to an instance of `Bar` through a reference of type `Foo`:

```
Foo foo = new Bar(5);
```

... and also check (at runtime) whether an object implements `Foo`:

```
if (o instanceof Foo) {
  System.err.println("It's a Foo!");
}
```

This latter case is typically the driver behind using marker interfaces; the former case offers little benefit as there are no methods that can be called on `Foo` (without first attempting a downcast).

Comment: There has to be a way JVM understands that this interface is a marker interface and if JVM encounters a marker interface it should take some action. If i declare an interface with no methods and hope that any class implementing it can be serialized , it'll not work :-)

Comment: @Pankaj No. The JVM doesn't care. It is the *Java code* that does the checking.

Comment: The answer given is pretty perfect and clear. I was going through "ObjectOutputStream" class and writeObject0 method is checking whether Object is of Serializable instance type(obj instanceof Serializable) or not. If not it is throwing NotSerializableException. Apart from that most of the regular classes like String, ArrayList etc already implementing Serializable interface, so sometimes it skips out from our head to check whether Class we want to serialize is implementing the interface.

Comment: @Pankaj did you get your answer(asked on  Pankaj Aug 5 '15 at 9:56) ? if yes then please let me know, i am also stuck with same question.

Comment: @uniquephase : the instanceof operator is used to check if our class implements a (marker)interface. So for eg if u serialize a class with out implementing the Serializable interface the condition yourObject instanceof Serializable will fail.

Comment: @bharatj _I dont think that is the case_. for example - `ArrayList` implements marker interface `RandomAccess` ; but its `get(index)` method does not check for either random access is supported or not (something like that). **My Que :** how the hell compiler know that with this marker interface i have to do this for this particular class. there has to be a mechanism ??

Comment: code - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList

Comment: @rootTraveller I will try my best to explain it. Marker interface are designed to be used by outside programs. For example I have developed an algorithm which needs Random access data structure, and let suppose input for this algorithm is List. Now how I can make sure that I'm using right collection? I cannot check for implementation type like Array List etc, because there can be other implementations apart from array which I don't know. Therefore marker interface can be used to check whether my algo is consuming right data structure with desired property.("instanceof")

Answer (score 5):

> then how it is handled by the JVM for the classes which implements
>   this marker interface?

Instances of class implementing a Java marker interface benefit from a specific behavior because some JDK classes or the  [HotSpot JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot) provide a specific behavior for them.

For example take the `Serializable` interface.
If you dig into `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` you can see that the serialization/unserialization behavior are implemented in.

Here is a snippet of [`ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.java#l1105) invoking by `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` that illustrates that :

```
public class ObjectOutputStream extends OutputStream implements ObjectOutput, ObjectStreamConstants {

   ...
   private void writeObject0(Object obj, boolean unshared) throws IOException   {
            ...    
            if (obj instanceof String) {
                writeString((String) obj, unshared);
            } else if (cl.isArray()) {
                writeArray(obj, desc, unshared);
            } else if (obj instanceof Enum) {
                writeEnum((Enum<?>) obj, desc, unshared);
            } else if (obj instanceof Serializable) {
                writeOrdinaryObject(obj, desc, unshared);
            } else {
                if (extendedDebugInfo) {
                    throw new NotSerializableException(
                        cl.getName() + "\n" + debugInfoStack.toString());
                } else {
                    throw new NotSerializableException(cl.getName());
                }
            }
            ...
    }
}
```

For the `Cloneable` interface, look at the `Object.clone()` method and you will see that it refers a native method that applies the `Cloneable` specification.

In the HotSpot source code, the [`src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp#l540), you can find the `Object.clone()` implementation :

```
JVM_ENTRY(jobject, JVM_Clone(JNIEnv* env, jobject handle))
  JVMWrapper("JVM_Clone");
  Handle obj(THREAD, JNIHandles::resolve_non_null(handle));
  const KlassHandle klass (THREAD, obj->klass());
  JvmtiVMObjectAllocEventCollector oam;

  // I skip all the processing that you can read in the actual source file
  ...

  return JNIHandles::make_local(env, oop(new_obj));
JVM_END
```

For this marker interface the behavior is not directly implemented in a JDK class but by the JVM itself but the general idea is the same.

> Can we create any new marker interfaces ?

If you create your own marker interfaces, you should do as the JVM and the JDK classes do to handle built-in instances of class implementing a Java marker interface : that is adding code to handle specifically the instances of your marker interfaces.
The very good answer of `Adamski` shows the general idea to do that.

Answer (score 4):

As far the compiler and the JVM are concerned, there is absolutely no difference between a marker interface and any other interface.

And yes, you can create marker interfaces as you please.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that there might be some logic behind the scenes. How else we get the CloneNotSupportedException when try calling clone() without implementing Cloneable, unless the compiler has some guidelines to check on few things when it sees the clone()!

http://javamagic.wordpress.com/2011/12/02/marker-interface-in-java-what-why-uses-etc/

As per this thread( [Confusion in marker interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294350/confusion-in-marker-interface) ), these are all Marker Interfaces .......... Serializable, Clonable, SingleThreadModel, EventListener, RandomAccess, Remote etc.

If there is no logic behind the scene OR no special instructions for JVM/compiler to treat them differently, how come they behave as ONLY what is expected out of them (& JVM/compiler understands the difference between Clonable & Serializable)?

Comment: You get the exception at runtime. *Ergo* the compiler has nothing do wth it.

Answer (score 0):

The marker interface helps identify that whether the object under inspection is actually a type (implemented interface) we are interested in. However it is not different than the other interfaces (except that they don't have any behavior obligation)

For example, the `ObjectOutputStream` can find that if a class implements `Serializable`, then the user has explicitly shown his consent that the object can be serialized.

Comment: Nrj: You mean to say JVM explicitly has some logic inside to handle serialization. that will be executed when we implement a class with Serializable interface?

Comment: No Srini, Its the ObjectOutputStream which checks for the Serializable check since ObjectOutputStream is the class which actually does the serialization.

Comment: @Nrj: Yes you are right. The word "serializable" is confusing in this context, as many novice programmers like myself take it to mean that "serializable" interface does the serialization, i.e. the process of converting the abstract data type to bytes. But as the literature shows, serializable interface is just a "marker" and the real work of converting ADT to bytes (I will call this the  process of getting metadata) is done by ObjectOutputStream. Similarly deserialization is done by ObjectInputStream.

Answer (score 0):

The word "serializable" is confusing in this context, as many novice programmers like myself take it to mean that "serializable" interface does the serialization, i.e. the process of converting the abstract data type to bytes. But as the literature shows, serializable interface is just a "marker" and the real work of converting ADT to bytes (I will call this the process of getting metadata) is done by ObjectOutputStream. Similarly deserialization is done by ObjectInputStream.

Answer (score -1):

Take Exampe of `clone()`. Actually `clone()` is defined inside `Object` class. But it is `protected`. You can use it only if your class is implementing `Cloneable` interface. So what happens is, when you implement `Cloneable`, you get the right to use `clone()`. Interface doesn't contain any methods! Got it ?

Comment: This explains nothing.