# How JVM handles marker interfaces internally?

Tags: java, marker-interfaces

Could any body explain me how JVM internally handles marker interfaces like:

```
Serializable
```

Comment: Just like any other interface...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791802/how-marker-interface-is-handled-by-jvm?rq=1

Comment: At SO itself it has been asked n times.

Answer (score 3):

Just like any other interface... Marker interface is not a language construct, it's just a term used to describe an interface without any methods.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is it is not different from any other interface. There is absolutely no difference between a marker interface and other interface.

You may check **[Marker Interface in Java: what, why, uses, etc.](http://geekexplains.blogspot.in/2009/10/marker-interface-in-java-what-why-uses.html)**

**On a side note:-**

If we take `java.io.Serializable` marker interface. Now this doesnot have any members defined in it.
So when a java class is to be serialized, then JVM should be intimiated in some way that if we want we can serialize this java class. So in this case, marker interfaces are used. So the java class which may be serialized has to implement the `java.io.Serializable` marker interface. Hence now we can initimate the JVM.

Comment: Link provide is helpful of course.