# How marker interface are identified by JVM?

Tags: java

I have gone through few question in stack overflow but could not find a suitable answer. So raising it for more clarity.

I know a marker interface is an interface with no methods. When we implement a marker interface for example Serializable it declares that the class implementing it becomes eligible for serialization.

My question is how JVM understands that the objects of class implementing Serializable interface should be serialized. If i write an interface with no methods and hope that objects of class that implements it will be serialized i'll not work that way.

Is it possible for us to create a custom marker class.?

Comment: Hope this helps you understand the concept:  [How marker interface is handled by jvm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791802/how-marker-interface-is-handled-by-jvm)

Comment: @biziclop The JVM 'understands' nothing, and has not been 'specifically programmed' in respect of `Serializable`. The *Java code* does the checking.

Comment: @EJP I didn't want to complicate things too much, hence the quotes. :)

Comment: @biziclop There's a difference between simplification and error, quotes or no quotes. The confusion you compounded is central to the question.

Comment: @EJP Yeah, in retrospect it probably did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They aren't 'identified by the JVM' at all. They're identified by the Java code that is interested in them, for example `ObjectOutputStream`, via the `instanceof` operator.

Comment: +1, but you may also mention isAssignableFrom if you dealing with Class<?>  instead of object instances.

Comment: @rkosegi Yes, that's another example.

Comment: @EJP : i think i am making sense now. You mean the implementation in ObjectOutputStream checks if the object has implemented the Serializable interface if yes perform wirteObject(objectToBeSerialized). So even i can write a marker interface and write a code that checks if an object is an instance of that marker interface and take appropriate action on it then.

Comment: @Pankaj That is correct.

Comment: @EJP: Thanks buddy :-)